# Как удалить файл BlueStacks_nxt.sys после деинсталяции BlueStacks? Отказано в доступе

Tags: cmd, администрирование

Пробую все возможные способы, и даже чистить папку **Temp**, которая кое как очистилась с помощью специальных программ.

В реестре файлы, принадлежащие **blueStacks**, не удаляются.

Как удалить в `cmd` (от имени администратора), если сообщение "*отказано в доступе*"?

[image: cmd]

В диспетчере задач процессов "BlueStacks" нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Получаем доступ

```
takeown /f "C:\Program Files\BlueStacks_nxt" /r /d y
icacls "C:\Program Files\BlueStacks_nxt" /grant:r %USERNAME%:f /t
```

2. Удаляем папку

```
rd "C:\Program Files\BlueStacks_nxt" /s /q
```